# Under "Psionics-Magic Transparency" what kind of powers is a half-fey immune to?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, magic, psionics, immunities

A [half-fey](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sp/20040213a) is immune to enchantment effects:

> **Original text from Fiend Folio:**
>
> Special Qualities: Half-fey have low-light vision and are immune to enchantment spells and effects.
>
> **Revised text from wizards:**
>
> Immunity to Enchantments (Ex): At 2nd level, a half-fey becomes immune to all spells and effects from the Enchantment school. This ability replaces the saving throw bonus against these effects included in the half-fey's base racial features.

Under the [Psionics-Magic transparency](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm) default rule, what psionic powers is the half-fey immune to?

> The default rule for the interaction of psionics and magic is simple: Powers interact with spells and spells interact with powers in the same way a spell or normal spell-like ability interacts with another spell or spell-like ability. This is known as psionics-magic transparency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [psionic powers overview of the telepathy discipline](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#telepathy):

> For the purpose of psionics-magic transparency, telepathy powers are equivalent to powers of the enchantment school (thus, creatures resistant to enchantment spells are equally resistant to telepathy powers).

Half-fey are immune to telepathy powers.